# R2R DAC in reverse

Tags: audio, dac, r2r

Knowing how voltage dividers work, this probably isn't possible. But, is there a way to run an audio signal back through an R2R arrangement and get 8bit digital signals back out without complex circuitry?

Comment: You can turn any DAC into an ADC by adding an analog comparator.

Comment: Where would I add it? Elaborate please.

Comment: Connect the DAC to one input, connect your analog voltage to the other, and connect the output to your logic. The logic (e.g., firmware running on a microcontroller) then runs an algorithm such as [successive approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_approximation_ADC) to determine what the analog voltage is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for a Flash ADC:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_ADC

You can't use the same arrangement though. You need a lot more resistors.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm guessing there isn't a way to do it without some form of an IC?

Comment: You could build the comparators out of transistors, but that sounds kinda painful. ICs make things easy!

Comment: Im for the ICs most of the time but a 6502 and the VIA plus some other bits and doodads and you suddenly find yourself running out of breadboard space. This is the main reason I chose an R2R DAC. I wonder if maybe instead of 255 comparators (just for 8 bits-

Comment: I use a different style? Is there another that may save space?

Comment: Just find an off the shelf SPI ADC or something... ?